# Difficult promise case - Sails - MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, promise, sails.js

I've been reading about promises. I would like to simplify the callbacks on my page. I do have one problem. I can't find any material online that matches my case.

I have two mongo collections. One containing the UserID and one containing the users information.

First i need to get the IDs

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5883ee4ed09e16a01aca63dc"),
"logo" : "logo.png",
"shortname" : "CSGO",
"longname" : "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive",
"starttime" : ISODate("2017-05-19T15:00:00Z"),
"status" : "Status",
"limit" : 5,
"teams" : [
    {
        "teamid" : ObjectId("5883faa13e72bb7c80b4f698"),
        "leaderid" : ObjectId("5883ee8f0cfc03217d0e6329"),
        "teamname" : "NAKdSquad",
        "locked" : false,
        "members" : [
            ObjectId("5883ee8f0cfc03217d0e6329")
        ]
    },
    {
        "teamid" : ObjectId("5884dd29b0dd0074050f2ef3"),
        "leaderid" : ObjectId("5883f4d7e87c76c06cff8f56"),
        "teamname" : "tomasSquad",
        "locked" : false,
        "members" : [
            ObjectId("5883f4d7e87c76c06cff8f56")
        ]
    }
]
}
```

The IDs i need to get are in an array, inside an array. "teams.members".
Currently i use the following string to get the IDs.

```
Turneringer.native(function (err, collection) {
    if (err) sails.log(err)

    collection.find({
        shortname: shortname,
        'teams.members': {
            $in: [ ObjectId(userid) ]
        }
    }, {
        _id: 0,
       'teams.members.$': 1
    }).toArray(function (err, resultTeam) {
       if (err) sails.log(err)
       sails.log(JSON.stringify(resultTeam))
       return resultTeam
    })
})
```

result:

```
[{"teams":[{"teamid":"5884dd29b0dd0074050f2ef3","leaderid":"5883f4d7e87c76c06cff8f56","teamname":"tomasSquad","locked":false,"members":["5883f4d7e87c76c06cff8f56"]}]}]`
```

The IDs come as an array, therefore i need to use some sort of loop. I've tried `.each`, `.forEach` & `.then` with a each-loop inside but didn't seem to be my solution.

I need help to find out how to loop the members so I can get a list of nicks from another collection.

Could someone help me forge this together? - I've tried for hours and I am now completely blank.

Best regards
OrKarstoft

EDIT:

This is the promise I've tried.

```
Turneringer.native(function (err, collection) {
    if (err) sails.log(err)

    collection.find({
        shortname: shortname,
        'teams.members': {
            $in: [ ObjectId(userid) ]
        }
    }, {
        _id: 0,
        'teams.members.$': 1
    }).toArray(function (err, resultTeam) {
        if (err) sails.log(err)
        sails.log(JSON.stringify(resultTeam))
        return resultTeam
    })
}).forEach(function (result) {
    sails.log(result)
    ^This gives error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined'
})
```

Comment: can you show what you've tried, otherwise you'll only get very generic answers about using `Array#reduce` or `Array#map` with `Promise.all`

Comment: Please show more of your code in order to resolve this better.

Comment: That is about what I've got. The promise I've made doesn't work. But I inserted it in the bottom of the post.

Comment: Whatever you want to do with resultTeam, you have to do from inside that callback function.